# Array of custom class implementing generics not allowing custom class with subclassed generic

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following scenario

```
class Human {}
class Child: Human {}
class Person<T: Human> {}

var people = [Person<Human>]()
people.append(Person<Child>())
```

yet on the line `people.append(Person<Child>())` I receive an error of

```
cannot convert value of type 'Person<Child>' to expected argument type 'Person<Human>'
```

This is really strange as doing the following works (which seems to be an identical situation)

```
var myArray = [Array<UIView>]()
myArray.append(Array<UIImageView>())
```

Would anyone have an understanding of why one way works and not the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you're not putting the case strongly enough. Define:

```
class Human {}
class Child: Human {}
struct Holder<T> {}
```

I made Holder a struct so no one can accuse us of cheating: Array is a struct, Holder is a struct. And I took away your constraint on the placeholder, reducing everything to the simplest possible form.

Now just assign an array of Child where an array of Human is expected:

```
var arr = Array<Human>()
arr = Array<Child>()
```

Fine. Now try it with a Holder:

```
var holder = Holder<Human>()
holder = Holder<Child>() // error
```

The parallelism now appears perfect: Array is a struct, Holder is a struct, and all we're doing is trying to assign polymorphically. So what's the problem?

The problem, as you have probably already suspected, is that you are not Apple. Apple writes the code, so they get to define Array and similar types as *covariant* on the parametrized type. But it isn't an automatic feature of the language — that is, it is not true for generics *in general*. And in particular, *you* don't get to do that for types *you* define.

So Apple's Array is covariant, but your Holder (or Person) is not, and there's nothing that allows you to switch covariance on.

You can see *why* Array is covariant. It is a very special case. An array is a collection of objects. Apple knows that an array of, say, Child objects is also in fact an array of Human objects, because every Child is a Human (polymorphism). So they have implemented covariance for arrays, to ensure that this is so.

But there is no such guarantee about your Person or my Holder. Swift doesn't know *what* you intend to do with the placeholder T. You can probably think of cases where substituting a `Holder<Child>` where a `Holder<Human>` is expected would be *wrong*. So Apple makes no assumptions in that direction.

---

I should add that it's important to distinguish the following:

```
class Human {}
class Child: Human {}
struct Holder<T> {
    let thing : T
}
let holder : Holder<Human> = Holder(thing:Child()) // fine
```

That's legal, but it has nothing whatever to do with what we've been talking about. Only one generic type is involved here: `Holder<Human>`. All we're doing is assigning a Child into `thing`, where a Human is expected. That's good old-fashioned non-generic polymorphism. But you still can't cast a `Holder<Human>` down to a `Holder<Child>`, even if `thing` *is* a Child, and you still can't assign a `Holder<Child>` where a `Holder<Human>` is expected.

Comment: And see this now-classic article on this very topic: http://nomothetis.svbtle.com/type-variance-in-swift