# Cast a Swift generic class to a protocol with a typealias

Tags: swift, generics

Am I crazy or shouldn't this swift code compile?

```
protocol Protocol {
  typealias Thing
}

class Class<X>: Protocol {
  typealias Thing = X
}

func test<X:Protocol where X.Thing == Int> () -> X {
  return Class<Int>()  // error: cannot convert return expression of type 'Class<Int>' to return type 'X'
}
```

I can't seem to cast the object to its protocol even though the generic type and aliastype match.

**EDIT:**

I came up with the code above by extracting the logic out of my existing code in an effort to simplify the problem.  I made some mistakes in doing so.  Here is an updated (and hopefully less confusing) code sample:

```
protocol Protocol {
    typealias Thing
}
class Class<X>: Protocol {
    typealias Thing = X
}
func test<Y: Protocol where Y.Thing == Int> () -> Y {
    return Class<Y.Thing>()
}
```

I expected the compiler to allow test() to compile with the result type being `Protocol<Int>`.

Comment: The definition of your `test` function says it needs to return an `X`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your return type is impossible in today's Swift. A protocol with an associated type (PAT) is abstract. Applying a where clause doesn't change that. Consider this code:

```
let x: <WHAT-GOES-HERE?> = test()
```

What type would `x` be here? There is nothing you could write there that would compile. What would `x.Type` return? What you want it to be is `Protocol where Protocol.Thing == Int`, but that's not a type in Swift. It's a type *constraint*. That's the only way PATs can be used today. That's why you can't have a property of type `CollectionType<Int>`, and why you can't write your `test()` function.

The solution is a type-eraser to convert your protocol into a concrete struct. For example:

```
protocol Protocol {
    typealias Thing
    func dosomething() -> Thing?
}
class Class<X>: Protocol {
    typealias Thing = X
    func dosomething() -> Thing? {
        return nil
    }
}

struct AnyProtocol<Thing> {
    var _dosomething: () -> Thing?
    func dosomething() -> Thing? {
        return _dosomething()
    }
}

func test() -> AnyProtocol<Int> {
    return AnyProtocol(_dosomething: Class<Int>().dosomething)
}
```

It is possible that some future version of Swift would automatically generate these type erasers for you, but I'm not aware of any specific Swift-evolution proposal for one, so we have to write them by hand today.

For more on building and using type erasers, see [A Little Respect for AnySequence](http://robnapier.net/erasure).

Comment: Excellent answer and exactly the type of explanation I was after.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I crazy or shouldn't this swift code compile?

You might be crazy, but I wouldn't use your code here as a test of that. Still, the code makes no sense, so the compiler is right to complain. It makes no sense to me either, so it's a little hard even for a human being to guess what you might mean, but perhaps you mean this:

```
protocol Protocol {
    typealias Thing
}
class Class<X>: Protocol {
    typealias Thing = X
}
func test<Y:Protocol where Y.Thing == Int> () -> Class<Y> {
    return Class<Y>()
}
```

But even though that compiles, I still don't see what you're getting at. For one thing, I don't see how the `Y` in `test` is going to be resolved by actual code. Maybe (judging here from the title) the problem is that you are expecting generic types to be castable to other generic types. They are not. For example, given class Animal and its subclass Dog, you cannot interchange between `MyGeneric<Animal>` and `MyGeneric<Dog>`.

Your comment also makes no sense:

> what I'm trying to do is cast `Class<Int>` to `Protocol<Int>`

There is no such type as `Protocol<Int>`. There are only particular adopters of Protocol that *specialize* Protocol so that Thing is Int.

Comment: If the problem is the thing I point to in my last paragraph, you might want to see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35787361/341994

Comment: Sorry, the dual use of X _is_ confusing.. but what I'm trying to do is cast Class<Int> to Protocol<Int> which should compile given that Class's typealias binds the two types together.

Comment: No it shouldn't. There is no such thing as `Protocol<Int>`. The whole notion makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it fails is simple: you're not respecting the specifics you yourself defined.

When you use generics, you have a generic type (in this case `X`) which doesn't just mean "anything that satisfies the constraints", but "something specific that satisfies the constraints".

So, if you do something like `let foo: Class<Int> = test()` your code could still look alright.
But then if you do something like

```
class AnotherClass<X>: Protocol {
  typealias Thing = X
}
let bar: AnotherClass<Int> = test()
```

you see clearly why the above is wrong.

The main concept here is, when you work with generics you can only use what the generic gives you. In this case, use only `X` and `X.Thing`, which is an `Int`. Nothing else, unless you add something to `Protocol` or other constraints in the function `test`

## Update:

I see now with the updated question. Look at Rob Napier answer, what you want is a Type Eraser. Though I think that the talk in swift-evolution on existential types could bring this feature in?

Comment: I updated the code since I had made a mistake.  The second code sample sets the return type of `test()` to be `Protocol where Protocol.Thing == Int`.  I don't expect your code to compile due to the casting, but I do expect to be able to use the returned value as if it was a reference to the protocol.

Comment: Have you seen an actual proposal for existential types, or is it still just chatter? (Hoping a real proposal comes forward eventually.)

Comment: @RobNapier What's an existential type? And when I ask that, I'm hoping you'll write an explanation on your blog! :)

Comment: I don't know if there's enough for a blog post but maybe. Existential types is a super-type-theory way of talking about types like Array. I don't mean Array<Any> but instead any Array. I shouldn't need to know what Element is to compute Array.count, but in Swift I do because I lack existential types. Similarly, CollectionType would be existential. In the Swift source, they call the "Any" type erasers "existential" since type-erasure is a good way to implement them. "There is a type that…" I can prove that by providing a concrete struct that fulfills the promise. Ok…maybe this is a blog post :)

Comment: This appears to address the topic https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160111/006367.html

Comment: Right now I speak from memory, but I remember one mega-post called something like "Completing Protocols Manifesto", and in the topics considered in there "Existential types" was an item. I think no real talk on it started yet though